# Finding a number in a range

Tags: microsoft-excel

Could you please help me with the below requirement.

I have maintained ranges in columns A and B.  Relevant values for each range are mentioned in column C.  For example, see below:

```
| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| 1        | 10       | A        |
| 15       | 20       | B        |
| 21       | 30       | C        |
```

Now I have another column E where I have inserted a number, for example 17. Now I would like to know in which range this number falls in so that relevant value from column C can be brought in.  In this example, 17 falls in the range of 15 to 20 which is in row 2 and whose value in column C is B.  Thus for the figure of 17, output should come as B.  In case I enter 25, the output should be C.  But if I enter 12, the output should be #N/A because this number doesn't fall under any range.

May I know if there is any excel formulae that I can use to get this type of output.  I prefer to use formulae rather than any coding.  Thanks for your time to guide me in this regard.

Warm regards,
Sridhar

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done - You need an extra line in the table to make it work.

I added the line

```
| 0        | 0        | #N/A     |
```

into the table as the first line, so the table now occupies **A1:C4**.

I use the `INDEX` function to decide which line I need to return.
To calculate the line, I use `SUMPRODUCT` to calculate the row that INDEX will use.
The full formula becomes:

```
=INDEX(C1:C4,SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A4<=D1),--(B1:B4>=D1),ROW(C1:C4)))
```

, with the value to be checked in `D1`

Running through the formula with **D1** containing `17`:

```
=INDEX(C1:C4,SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A4<=17),--(B1:B4>=17),ROW(C1:C4)))
=INDEX(C1:C4,SUMPRODUCT(--({0,1,15,21}<=17),--({0,10,20,30}>=17),{1,2,3,4}))
=INDEX(C1:C4,SUMPRODUCT(--({True,True,True,False}),--({False,False,True,True}),{1,2,3,4}))
=INDEX(C1:C4,SUMPRODUCT({1,1,1,0}),({0,0,1,1}),{1,2,3,4}))
=INDEX(C1:C4,(1*0*1 + 1*0*2 + 1*1*3 + 0*1*4))
=INDEX(C1:C4,3)
="B"
```

If the number falls outside the range, there will not be a part in the SUMPRODUCT where the line of values does not equal `0`, so it will return the first value in the range, which will be the #N/A. Same formula, but with `12` in **D1**:

```
=INDEX(C1:C4,SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A4<=12),--(B1:B4>=12),ROW(C1:C4)))
=INDEX(C1:C4,SUMPRODUCT(--({0,1,15,21}<=12),--({0,10,20,30}>=12),{1,2,3,4}))
=INDEX(C1:C4,SUMPRODUCT(--({True,True,False,False}),--({False,False,True,True}),{1,2,3,4}))
=INDEX(C1:C4,SUMPRODUCT({1,1,0,0}),({0,0,1,1}),{1,2,3,4}))
=INDEX(C1:C4,(1*0*1 + 1*0*2 + 0*1*3 + 0*1*4))
=INDEX(C1:C4,0)
="#N/A"
```

*It's not technically **#N/A** , it's an array of all possible answers, but as we didn't enter the formula as an array formula, it only gives us the first value*